# Porting new feature to old kernel version

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Need some Kernel expert advices.

Wondering is it safe to patch only TPM related code from V4.14 into V4.8?
Seems like TPM modules change a lot from V4.8 to V4.14. For some reason we have to stick on V4.8 Kernel and use new TPM feature presented in V4.14.
What else I need to pay attention about for doing this?

BTW, this will be in a production products all world around.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why the hell would you trust us? Test it.

Comment: First of all, I would **highly** recommend to consider `v4.9.y` instead of `v4.8` since it's an LTS one and many things are backported there. To the topic, the distance might be drastical, though you need to check it yourself.